# How to do e2e testing for client side download functionality using cypress?

Tags: node.js, testing, cypress, xlsx, e2e-testing

I am trying to write e2e test case for download button using cypress.

1. It's a client side download functionality, it'll not hot the backend
2. When I'll click on download button, it's download the file.
3. I want assertion like: Once download button is clicked i want to verify the path by checking below downloaded path.

[image]

**My Code**

```
it('Download button should work', () => {
        cy.get('.download').click().then(($identifier) => {
            cy.debug($identifier)
        });
    })
```

Can anyone help me how can i get the download path using cypress ?

Comment: Did you look at e.g. https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/testing-dom__download?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, is it required use any plugins for cypress ?